# How to upload an image and send its src as binary data?

Tags: javascript

I want to read in an image data and send the source of the image so the server. I was using a FileReader that creates a Base64-String. As the String can become very, I want to send the image source as binary data, how can I do it?

currently done via base64:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.readAsDataURL( file );

reader.onloadend = function(){

   var source = this.result; //i need to send this to the server
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Javascript:**

```
$("#browse").change(function () {
    var files = this.files;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var name = this.value;
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $("#preview").append("<a>'" + name + "'</a><img src='" + e.target.result + "' width='30' height='30' />");
        alert(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="browse" />
<div id="preview"></div>
```

I think, you can send `e.target.result` to server in the way you want to.

<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/3QyEB/